# Web crawler that downloads all the links in a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

i am a python beginner and have written a code to download all the links in the url specified. Is there a better way to do this and is the below code correct?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re
import requests

def get_page(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r.status_code)
    content = r.text
    return content

if __name__ =="__main__":
    url = 'http://developer.android.com'
    content = get_page(url)
    content_pattern = re.compile('<a href=(.*?)>.*?</a>')
    result = re.findall(content_pattern, content)
    for link in result:
        with open('download.txt', 'wb') as fd:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
                fd.write(chunk)
```

Comment: what does the code __name__=="__main__" compare? what does it mean?

Comment: It means; if this file is a module for importing to the another file or entrance of the program

Comment: And also this code seems correct, what are you asking for ?

Comment: @myildirim how do i specify the chunk_size ?

Comment: This code snippet uses requests module, you can find in it's document what you search for http://www.python-requests.org/en/v0.14.2/api/

Comment: @myildirim thanks, right now the webpage is getting downloaded i cant get the links in webpage and my goal is to download the stuff in those links. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to investigate the linux `wget` command which is able to do what you want already. If you really want a python solution then [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) and [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) can perform the HTTP requests and parse the HTML respectively.

Comment: i want a python solution and beautiful soup is used for parsing. Is it necessary to pass. Why is r.text not enough ?

Comment: You don't want to parse HTML by yourself, especially not with a regex. You will get more reliable results if you use a proper library. It has been covered very well in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/170865

Comment: thanks, right now the webpage whose link i provide is getting downloaded i cant get the links in webpage and my goal is to download the stuff in those links. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import requests

def get_links(url):

    r = requests.get(url)
    contents = r.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)
    links =  []
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        try:
            links.append(link['href'])
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return links

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = sys.argv[1]
    print get_links(url)
    sys.exit()
```